# Figuring out the dates for a given week

Tags: bash, date

With `date -d @[some_timestamp] +"%U"` the end result is a number between 0-53, which represents the week in which the `[some_timestamp]` is located. So if I have an arbitrary timestamp *ie* `1426815663`, the end result is [week] `11`

**Q:** Is there a way for `date` also stating the *starting date* and *ending date* for week `11`?

Comment: I suggest you use a converter such as python date the import to date command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested for dates surrounding a years end, but should give you enough to work out the rest:

```
fdotw=$(($1 - ($(date -d @$1 +"%u") - 1) * 3600 * 24))
ldotw=$(($fdotw + 6 * 24 * 3600))
date -d @$fdotw +"%F"
date -d @$ldotw +"%F"

me@mylaptop:/home/me >fdotw=$((1428909297 - ($(date -d @1428909297 +"%u") - 1) * 3600 * 24))
me@mylaptop:/home/me >ldotw=$(($fdotw + 6 * 24 * 3600))
me@mylaptop:/home/me >date -d @$fdotw +"%F"
2015-04-13
me@mylaptop:/home/me >date -d @$ldotw +"%F"
2015-04-19
me@mylaptop:/home/me >
```